# Combining gRPC standard and async methods in the same Python server

Tags: python, async-await, grpc, grpc-python

I have a gRPC server, written in Python 3.6. This server follows the pattern described in the gRPC [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_server.py) as follows:

```py
from concurrent import futures
import logging

import grpc

import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc


class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)

    # ...

    def ReadRemoteData(self, request, context):
        return fetch_some_data_io_bound()


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    serve()
```

In my server application, there are a lot more methods, but in general is more of the same.

There are a number of these methods that are currently a bottleneck for my server and I would like to optimize those by running them using `async` (these methods spend good time waiting on IO so they are a good candidate).

The newest versions of `grpc` now support `async` as seen in [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/async_greeter_server.py), by creating an async server with `server = grpc.aio.server()`.

My problem is the following:

The server has a lot of gRPC methods, many of which are very complex. I would like to avoid rewriting any method that is not currently a bottleneck and leave them as they are. I would like to rewrite only those methods that would benefit from an async implementation, which is just a small fraction of the total. I can't change the `.proto` definition to split the service into async/non-async, for backwards-compatibility reasons.

**The question is, is it possible to combine, somehow, async and non async methods in the same gRPC service?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The application needs to create the asyncio server with an extra argument which is `migration_thread_pool`. This is indeed an essential feature for migration.

See documentation at https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html#grpc.aio.server

```
import asyncio
from concurrent import futures
import logging

import grpc

import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc


class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)

    # ...

    def ReadRemoteData(self, request, context):
        return fetch_some_data_io_bound()


async def serve():
    server = grpc.aio.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    await server.start()
    await server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    asyncio.run(serve())
```

Comment: The answer was right under my nose. Thank you!